# Best way to program a nightly data transfer, identity column running high

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, data-transfer

I'm writing an application that needs to synchronize its own database with another database every night. When the data is pulling pulled over, it's also being transformed programatically in quite a complex way.

Now I see two possible approaches:

- method A: every night I delete all previously imported rows, and do a full reimport, this method is expensive but easy to program, maintain, overall robust
- method B: I save a reference to the original data for every imported row and do an insert, update, or delete if the data is respectively new, changed or removed, (keeping the reference alone is quite complex because there's no simple one-to-one relation)

Clearly method B is more complex and might more easily lead to bugs, so I prefer using method A. However since about 100,000 rows are being inserted every night, the identity column will run very high over time. Doing a simple reset to 1 every night is not an option since the rows that are imported are actually being mixed with other rows that have nothing to do with the data transfer, this last set rows has to remain unaffected by the transfer.

The main question I have about this is whether it's a problem at all that our identity column will run high (about 36 million increase every year). It's not tidy, but will there eventually be a performance hit, and what will happen if we ever reach the maximum int value? Has anyone faced similar challenges and can share their experience?

Comment: This question might be better suited for the programmers stack exchange as it is more geared around best practice and implementation. :) http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: whats the data type of your identity column?  Is it an int / big int.

Comment: Use a GUID for the unique row identifier. You will never run out and shouldn't hit a dupe for ID in a few hundred thousand years of use even at extremely high insert volumes.

Comment: GUIDs are expensive because of their length. I definitely don't recommend a GUID for this scenario.

Comment: `GUID` is 16 bytes, `BigInt` is 17 bytes (`numeric` data type). `GUID`s will be faster to write, read, transfer and less expensive to store than a `BigInt`, as long as the poster is using SQL Server 2008 or newer. If he is using something older, then a `GUID` will not be a native data type, and therefore he'd be forced to use a string or binary type representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will there eventually be a performance hit

I don't see why there should be. The size of the field is the same (say, 32 bit), so all operations with it would be performed with the same speed, whether the value of the field is 10 or 2,000,000,000.

If your identity column is int (32 bit), then it will last for `2,147,483,647 / 36,000,000 = 59` years.

It is very easy to check what would happen when you reach the maximum 2,147,483,647. Create a table in tempdb. (I'm using SQL Server 2008 for this test).

```
USE [tempdb]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BigTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Data] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BigTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Set identity to high value:

```
USE [tempdb]
GO

DBCC CHECKIDENT ("[dbo].[BigTable]", RESEED, 2147483645);
```

Try to insert 10 rows:

```
USE [tempdb]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[BigTable]
([Data])
VALUES
(0)

GO 10
```

This is what I get in the output window:

```
Beginning execution loop

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type int.
Arithmetic overflow occurred.
** An error was encountered during execution of batch. Continuing.
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type int.
Arithmetic overflow occurred.
** An error was encountered during execution of batch. Continuing.
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type int.
Arithmetic overflow occurred.
** An error was encountered during execution of batch. Continuing.
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type int.
Arithmetic overflow occurred.
** An error was encountered during execution of batch. Continuing.
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type int.
Arithmetic overflow occurred.
** An error was encountered during execution of batch. Continuing.
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type int.
Arithmetic overflow occurred.
** An error was encountered during execution of batch. Continuing.
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type int.
Arithmetic overflow occurred.
** An error was encountered during execution of batch. Continuing.
Batch execution completed 10 times.
```

This is the result:

```
USE [tempdb]
GO

SELECT [ID] ,[Data]
FROM [dbo].[BigTable]
GO


ID  Data
2147483645  0
2147483646  0
2147483647  0


DBCC CHECKIDENT ("[tempdb].[dbo].[BigTable]", NORESEED);

Checking identity information: current identity value '2147483647', current column value '2147483647'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

So, yes there will be problems when you exhaust all int values.
You can use [bigint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187745.aspx) instead. It is 64-bit (8 bytes, not 16) and will last much-much-much longer: `9,223,372,036,854,775,807 / 36,000,000 = 256,204,778,801` years
The performance of bigint is pretty much the same as int on 64-bit computers. It may be slower than int just because it is twice the size and the server will have to read/write twice amount of bytes to the disk and use twice amount of memory.

In terms of performance what is really important is that you rebuild indexes and update statistics on your table after you delete a lot of rows and add a lot of rows to it, because all statistics would be severely skewed. Here I mean performance of the rest of the system that would use this table, not the process of deleting and adding rows.

To improve the performance of the nightly sync process that deletes a lot of rows and adds a lot of rows consider disabling all indexes on the table before the changes and enabling (with rebuild) them back after the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You'll manage so long as your identity is a 64 bit int or better. It's not ideal, but it'll work for a few years until you decide you really need to really refator.

Yes, you could build an ideal solution, but it sounds like you need a "good enough" solution for now... Which is what Method A is.